# Form.ShowDialog() causes 'Invalid parameter' error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing a weird issue.

I created a small WinForms project containing a main form and an auxiliary one. I create the second form inside the first one in a code which resembles this one:

```
private void btnOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewForm form = new NewForm(value1, value2);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I use the `ShowDialog()` method, the program fails immediately after method execution with an `Invalid parameter` error, while the regular `Show()` method works fine. Via stacktrace, it says I can't use the same form as owner to the new one, but then how am I supposed to show a modal dialog, calling from the main form?

Main window constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Auxiliary form constructor:

```
public VectorPlot(Point2D OriginalVector, Point2D RotatedVector)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _originalVector = OriginalVector;
    _rotatedVector = RotatedVector;
}
```

Main window call to auxiliary window:

```
VectorPlot Plot = new VectorPlot(OriginalVector, ModifiedVector);
Plot.ShowDialog();
```

Paint event:

```
private void VectorPlot_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
    {
        GraphicsContainer container = g.BeginContainer(new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 300f, 300f), new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 300f, 300f), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 300f, 350f));
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray), 150f, 0f, 150f, 300f);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray), 0f, 150f, 300f, 150f);

        float xOrigVect =  (float)_originalVector.X;
        float yOrigVect = (float)_originalVector.Y;
        float xRotVect = (float)_rotatedVector.X;
        float yRotVect = (float)_rotatedVector.Y;

        xOrigVect = 150f + xOrigVect;
        yOrigVect = 150f - yOrigVect;
        xRotVect = 150f + xRotVect;
        yRotVect = 150f - yRotVect;

        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2f), 150f, 150f, xOrigVect, yOrigVect);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), 150f, 150f, xRotVect, yRotVect);

        g.DrawString("Legenda: ", new System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 8.0f), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0f, 310f));
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2f), 0f, 330f, 10f, 330f);
        g.DrawString("Vetor original", new System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 8.0f), Brushes.Black, new PointF(10f, 322f));
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), 0f, 340f, 10f, 340f);
        g.DrawString("Vetor rotacionado", new System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 8.0f), Brushes.Black, new PointF(10f, 332f));
        g.EndContainer(container);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Parâmetro inválido.
Source=System.Drawing
StackTrace:
   em System.Drawing.Graphics.get_Clip()
   em System.Drawing.Graphics.GetContextInfo()
   em System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsGraphics.FromGraphics(Graphics g, ApplyGraphicsProperties properties)
   em System.Windows.Forms.WindowsGraphicsWrapper..ctor(IDeviceContext idc, TextFormatFlags flags)
   em System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground(IDeviceContext dc, Rectangle bounds)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
InnerException:
```

Comment: What the code in the constructor.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria `InitializeComponent()` (automatic generated) and set for the 2 parameters I have. On parent form, only `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Your constructor is doing too much work and gets the native window created *before* you call Show/Dialog().  That's pretty unhealthy, you left no breadcrumbs why this is the case.  Giving the dialog an explicit owner instead of leaving it up to Winforms to find one is a workaround, use ShowDialog(this).

Comment: @HansPassant I need info from outside to paint a graphic in `Paint` event. Is there a better way to pass this, instead of using the constructor?

Comment: I doubt the arguments have anything to do with it.  You are asking questions about code we cannot see.  If you want to debug it then add the Load event handler to the dialog form and set a breakpoint on it.  Look at the call stack to see what statement caused the window to be created.

Comment: @HansPassant unfortunately I chose a bad time to post the question here since I'm not having access to code right now (I have it in another machine). I'm posting the stack trace here ASAP.

Comment: What .NET version are you using? Is this a compact framework?

Comment: @MaciejJureczko not compact. V.4.5 under Windows 8.

Comment: @HansPassant just got the stacktrace.

Comment: Please post the code in your Load EventHandler for the problematic Form.

Comment: @MarkHall how may I get the generated code?

Comment: @Mauren I am not talking about the generated code, something is causing a problem when you Load the Form, I was talking about the [Form_Load EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) If you are not using that event ignore my comment

Comment: @MarkHall I posted my `Paint` event above.

Comment: Get rid of this: `using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)`.  It's disposing a Graphics object you didn't create.  Just use the `e.Graphics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't pass the parameter in form.ShowDialog() method this will take default to current window / form as owner. so you can try like.

```
form.ShowDialog(App.OpenForms[0]); // as default form
```

or

```
form.ShowDialog(this); // to make the current window as owner for the form.
```

**EDIT::**

The normal way Windows (Win32 and WinForms.Net) handles this is to wait for the MessageQueue to run empty and then process all invalidated screen areas. That is efficient because when something changes that usually cascades into other things (controls) changing as well.

Here is your answer you have to create new usercontrol for the painting the vectors and use usercontrols paint event to get the task done. check to code below.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Form2 Plot = new Form2(new Point2D(10, 10), new Point2D(100, 100));
                Plot.ShowDialog();

        }



 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Point2D _originalVector;
        private Point2D _rotatedVector;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Point2D OriginalVector, Point2D RotatedVector)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _originalVector = OriginalVector;
            _rotatedVector = RotatedVector;
        }

        private void userControl11_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
                                using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
                {
                    GraphicsContainer container = g.BeginContainer(
                          new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 300f, 300f)
                        , new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 300f, 300f)
                        , GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 300f, 350f));
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray), 150f, 0f, 150f, 300f);
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray), 0f, 150f, 300f, 150f);

                    float xOrigVect = (float)_originalVector.X;
                    float yOrigVect = (float)_originalVector.Y;
                    float xRotVect = (float)_rotatedVector.X;
                    float yRotVect = (float)_rotatedVector.Y;

                    xOrigVect = 150f + xOrigVect;
                    yOrigVect = 150f - yOrigVect;
                    xRotVect = 150f + xRotVect;
                    yRotVect = 150f - yRotVect;

                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2f), 150f, 150f, xOrigVect, yOrigVect);
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), 150f, 150f, xRotVect, yRotVect);

                    g.DrawString("Legenda: ", new System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 8.0f), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0f, 310f));
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2f), 0f, 330f, 10f, 330f);
                    g.DrawString("Vetor original", new System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 8.0f), Brushes.Black, new PointF(10f, 322f));
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), 0f, 340f, 10f, 340f);
                    g.DrawString("Vetor rotacionado", new System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 8.0f), Brushes.Black, new PointF(10f, 332f));
                    g.EndContainer(container);
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `Application.OpenForms[0]` fails as well.

Comment: by user control you mean WPF ones?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should provide a parameter in this method. Try:

```
form.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: I tried this as well. It also fails, just like the parameterless one.

Comment: What will happen if you CATCH the exception and immediately do a SECOND "form.ShowDialog();"?

Comment: I tried this:   

    `try
    {
        Plot.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException except)
    {
        Plot.ShowDialog();
    }`

but it didn't seem to catch the exception.

Comment: Strange. Try it without specifying the exception type: 

`try { Plot.ShowDialog(); } catch (Exception except) { Plot.ShowDialog(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
form.ShowDialog(this);
```

Can you paste your stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to my stacktrace right now, but this one also fails.